# Create saw fin shape in Processing

Tags: math, geometry, processing, bezier, curve

I'm trying to recreate this image using Processing. How to make the red saw fins?

[image: red saw shape]

My thought process given the image is symmetrical over a few axis was to break it up. I'm struggling with the "red saw fins". It looks like I have to use a bezier to create the lines, then fill them in. If I'm able to create 1 fin, then I can rotate a copy of it on the axis to spin it around. https://processing.org/reference/bezier_.html

Comment: This is a tiny picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tiny picture. Enlarge it, and then load it into a tool for drawing bezier curves. You know the three fixed coordinates (the two coordinates at the circle, and the tip) and you know the general tangents along which your control points will need to be:

[image]

You also know that the control points and the on-curve points need to form a box that surrounds the actual curve (e.g. the curve cannot go outside that box) as a property of Bezier curves.

So now: you play around in finding the correct points. You can use something like Inkscape or Photoshop or Illustrator to see which curve looks good enough, and then you copy the coordinates over into your own program, or you just draw it out on a grid and find the rough coordinates simply by looking at your grid and then play around with values near to where you think.

And then when you have the missing control points, you draw it in processing as a shape:

```
void draw() {
  // draw the inner circle with a "fat" stroke
  strokeWeight(20);
  // assuming center mode
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 100, 100);

  // reset that stroke fatness
  strokeWeight(1);
  // make sure we'll be rotating about the center of the sketch
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  // and then start drawing eight 'teeth'
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    beginShape();
    // we know where p1, p2, and p3 are.
    vertex(p1.x, p1.y);
    // and we "guessed" at c1, c2, c3, and c4.
    bezierVertex(c1.x, c1.y, c2.y, c2.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    bezierVertex(c3.x, c3.y, c4.y, c4.y, p3.x, p3.y);
    // We leave the shape "open" in case you want both stroke and fill
    endShape();
    // we're drawing eight teeth, so we need to rotate by 2*PI/8 each time
    rotate(0.25 * PI);
  }
}
```

Comment: Took me almost a year to learn about Bezier Curves. I ended up using Inkscape to trace over the source image, then I found out that Inkscape uses a different coordinate system to Processing..

Anyway, thanks for your help! Here's the result: https://streamable.com/cu2p3 ::)

Answer (score 2):

Just play with control points of Bezier curves to provide needed form.

This is quick-made example in Delphi.

Points P0-P3 give the first side of tooth (concave), points P3-P6 give the second side of tooth.

Rin and ROut are inner and outer radii of saw, RM is middle radius used for control points' calculation.

Inside loop `an` is base angle for a tooth, `an1` is slightly shifted to provide curvature for concave arc, `an2` is ending angle (same as base angle of the next tooth) and `an3` is middle angle for control points of convex arc.

[image]

```
var
  P: array[0..6] of TPoint;
  i, N, CX, CY, Rin, ROut, RM: integer;
  an, an1, an2, an3: Double;
begin
  Rin := 100;
  ROut := 170;
  RM := (RIn + ROut) div 2;
  N := 8;
  CX := 350;
  CY := 350;
  for i := 0 to 7 do begin
    an := i * 2 * Pi / N;
    an1 := an + 0.25 * Pi / N;
    an2 := an + 2 * Pi / N;
    an3 := an + Pi / N;
    P[0] := Point(Round(CX + Rin * Cos(an)), Round(CY + Rin * Sin(an)));
    P[1] := Point(Round(CX + RM * Cos(an1)), Round(CY + RM * Sin(an1)));
    P[2] := Point(Round(CX + RM * Cos(an1)), Round(CY + RM * Sin(an1)));
    P[3] := Point(Round(CX + ROut * Cos(an)), Round(CY + ROut * Sin(an)));
    P[4] := Point(Round(CX + RM * Cos(an3)), Round(CY + RM * Sin(an3)));
    P[5] := Point(Round(CX + RM * Cos(an3)), Round(CY + RM * Sin(an3)));
    P[6] := Point(Round(CX + RIn * Cos(an2)), Round(CY + RIn * Sin(an2)));
    Canvas.PolyBezier(P);
    Canvas.Ellipse(CX - 3 * RIn div 4, CY - 3 * RIn div 4,
                   CX + 3 * RIn div 4, CY + 3 * RIn div 4);
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you outlined the process of how you came up with these points. Also please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, so the code you posted won't work in OP's language.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this, and you got a similar output result but the Delphi/math is over my head.